# CSS selector grouping algorithm implemented in C++

Tags: c++, algorithm

I'm developing a CSS minifier which will group together selectors that have common declarations, among other things. I've wrote the CSS parser which is functional but what I'm having trouble with is; thinking of the best way to programmatically group the selectors together, based on common declarations. Right now, the parser instantiates a CssBlock object with the selector name (i.e. h1, h6, div, etc) as a constructor argument. Then it parses out the declarations from the selector, splits each one into a property / value pair (i.e. margin:0), and inserts them into a `map<std::string, std::string>` member variable in that object. I guess what I have to do is, loop through the objects, check for common declarations, and then group those together.. But how can I do so optimally so that there aren't extra groups which could be included with other groups? Or so that each group isn't created around one declaration but multiple? Hopefully I'm making sense... If not, please just say so in the comments and I will try to explain more clearly.